# How to Toggle Multiple divs with defferent effect on each div

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I have a multiple divs each has its own position. what I want is to toggle each div when a text inside the div is clicked I am new in Javascript so please bear with me. I know how to do it by just toggling one div like i did below.

```
var para = document.querySelectorAll('.wrap div p');
      for (var i = 0; i < para.length; i++) {
          para[i].addEventListener('click', expand);
      }

      function expand(e) {
       if ((e.target === para[2]) && (document.querySelector('.wrap #three').style.width === '15%')) {
             document.querySelector('.wrap #three').style.width = '100%';
           }else{
             document.querySelector('.wrap #three').style.width = '15%';

           }
       }
```

I also tried using if else statement but it just expands the div I couldn't shrink it back to its position.. I know there is an easy way to achieve this but I couldn't figure out.

```js
var para = document.querySelectorAll('.wrap div p');
for (var i = 0; i < para.length; i++) {
  para[i].addEventListener('click', expand);
}

function expand(e) {
  if (e.target === para[0]) {
    document.querySelector('.wrap #one').style.width = '100%';
  } else if (e.target === para[1]) {
    document.querySelector('.wrap #two').style.width = '100%';

  } else if (e.target === para[2]) {
    document.querySelector('.wrap #three').style.width = '100%';

  } else if (e.target === para[3]) {
    document.querySelector('.wrap #four').style.width = '100%';

  } else if (e.target === para[4]) {
    document.querySelector('.wrap #five').style.width = '100%';

  } else if (e.target === para[5]) {
    document.querySelector('.wrap #six').style.width = '100%';

  } else if (e.target === para[6]) {
    document.querySelector('.wrap #seven').style.width = '100%';

  }
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.wrap div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fdfdfd;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.wrap div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  right: -150px;
  top: 27%;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrap p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Halvetica', sans-serif;
}

.wrap #one {
  position: absolute;
  width: 21%;
}

.wrap #one:before {
  background: #FF1D55;
}

.wrap #one p {
  right: -8px;
}

.wrap #two {
  position: absolute;
  width: 18%;
}

.wrap #two:before {
  background: #FFE31A;
}

.wrap #two p {
  right: -23px;
}

.wrap #three {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
}

.wrap #three:before {
  background: #00E2AA;
}

.wrap #three p {
  right: 2px;
}

.wrap #four {
  position: absolute;
  width: 12%;
}

.wrap #four:before {
  background: #B90CB4;
}

.wrap #four p {
  right: -13px;
}

.wrap #five {
  position: absolute;
  width: 9%;
}

.wrap #five:before {
  background: #FF3400;
}

.wrap #five p {
  right: -5px;
}

.wrap #six {
  position: absolute;
  width: 6%;
}

.wrap #six:before {
  background: #30B7E2;
}

.wrap #six p {
  right: -18px;
}

.wrap #seven {
  position: absolute;
  width: 3%;
}

.wrap #seven:before {
  background: #220054;
}

.wrap #seven p {
  right: -12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="one">
    <p>About</p>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <p>Services</p>
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <p>Blog</p>
  </div>
  <div id="four">
    <p>Follow</p>
  </div>
  <div id="five">
    <p>Team</p>
  </div>
  <div id="six">
    <p>Contact</p>
  </div>
  <div id="seven">
    <p>History</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope I explain everything clearly. any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use `classList.add/remove` instead of adding inline style through javascript.
In  your code you are attaching event to `p` which occupy a very small area, I have added a class `p` so that it's background can be visible and it will be easy to click.

Also you dont need to target each element and add class to it.

In this example get the  target element and it's parent and `toggle` class

```js
var para = document.querySelectorAll('.wrap div p');
for (let i = 0; i < para.length; i++) {

  para[i].addEventListener('click', expand);
}

function expand(e) {

  if (e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('fullWidth')) {
    e.target.parentNode.classList.remove('fullWidth')
  } else {
    e.target.parentNode.classList.add('fullWidth')
  }

}
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.wrap div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fdfdfd;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.wrap div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  right: -150px;
  top: 27%;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrap p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Halvetica', sans-serif;
}

.wrap #one {
  position: absolute;
  width: 21%;
}

.wrap #one:before {
  background: #FF1D55;
}

.wrap #one p {
  right: -8px;
}

.wrap #two {
  position: absolute;
  width: 18%;
}

.wrap #two:before {
  background: #FFE31A;
}

.wrap #two p {
  right: -23px;
}

.wrap #three {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
}

.wrap #three:before {
  background: #00E2AA;
}

.wrap #three p {
  right: 2px;
}

.wrap #four {
  position: absolute;
  width: 12%;
}

.wrap #four:before {
  background: #B90CB4;
}

.wrap #four p {
  right: -13px;
}

.wrap #five {
  position: absolute;
  width: 9%;
}

.wrap #five:before {
  background: #FF3400;
}

.wrap #five p {
  right: -5px;
}

.wrap #six {
  position: absolute;
  width: 6%;
}

.wrap #six:before {
  background: #30B7E2;
}

.wrap #six p {
  right: -18px;
}

.wrap #seven {
  position: absolute;
  width: 3%;
}

.wrap #seven:before {
  background: #220054;
}

.wrap #seven p {
  right: -12px;
}

p {
  background: greenyellow
}

.fullWidth {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="one">
    <p>About</p>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <p>Services</p>
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <p>Blog</p>
  </div>
  <div id="four">
    <p>Follow</p>
  </div>
  <div id="five">
    <p>Team</p>
  </div>
  <div id="six">
    <p>Contact</p>
  </div>
  <div id="seven">
    <p>History</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: brk. i think I couldn't explain right I actually want each div to expand to full width just like the code you provided in the top. but also I want it to go back to its original position.  so if I click on the first div it should expand which is working perfect but when I click on it again it should go back to its position

Comment: brk. i just did the same code and I was going to reply that it works then i saw your reply. anyways thanx a lot for help brother.